# Colored text in JTextPane gets messy when appending new strings

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, colors, jtextpane

I am implementing a SNMP-listener with a GUI. The GUI is supposed to print the parsed SNMP-traps in different color based on their severity. To do this I have used JTextPane.

Right now the program is fully functioning, I can append traps in different colors.

But the colors change and text get messed up, so that it is not readable, sometimes when appending new strings. For example some newly appended line take the color of an old appended line and vice versa. Also the red I am using becomes dark red, and the text is "smudgy", io the text does not have sharp lines. These problems disappear when resizing the widow, but come back when scrolling or appending new information.

I have tried to repaint and I have tried added a background color, but it made no difference.

Anyone else had this problem?

This is the code I am using to append text:

```
private void appendToPane(String msg, JTextPane p, Color c) {
    Style style = p.addStyle("I am a style", null);
    StyleConstants.setForeground(style, c);
    StyledDocument doc = p.getStyledDocument();
    try {
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), msg, style);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

It is working, the only problem is that the text gets messed up when scrolling or appending new text. 
With messed up I mean:
    - The upper or lower half of a row disappear (leaving half unreadable letters)
    - The text partly changes color (red becomes dark red for some sections)
    - Two rows change color with each other. (a green section gets a red row, a red section gets a green row)
    - The letters looks smudgy (the letters does not have sharp lines)

All these problems disappear when resizing the window, but reappears when scrolling or appending new text.

Answer (score 1):

> For example some newly appended line take the color of an old appended line and vice versa

Yes, inserted text will inherit the attributes of the previous text unless you specify the attributes for the inserted text.

The basic code for appending text at the end of the text pane would be something like:

```
//  Define a keyword attribute

SimpleAttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setForeground(keyWord, Color.RED);
StyleConstants.setBackground(keyWord, Color.YELLOW);
StyleConstants.setBold(keyWord, true);

//  Adding a new line of text

try
{
    StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\nEnd of text", keyWord );
}
```

> . Also the red I am using becomes dark red, and the text is "smudgy", io the text does not have sharp lines

Maybe you are using transparent backgrounds. See [Backgrounds With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for problems when doing this.

If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for this and all future questions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried redrawing the background behind it before appending the new string?
Or if you do not have a background, maybe adding one to be drawn before you append the new string, even if it is the same color as the current background.

The reason I say this, is perhaps the text is layering upon itself and that is why this is happening.